Is there a way I can use snakemake to generate files based on sequence in a list?
#Make 1 library.csv for a pair of ATAC and RNA seq accession numbers
def read_rna_accession():
    with open('rna_accessions.txt') as f:
        samples = [sample for sample in f.read().split('\n') if len(sample) > 0]  # Remove empty lines
        return samples

def read_atac_accession():
    with open('atac_accessions.txt') as f:
        samples = [sample for sample in f.read().split('\n') if len(sample) > 0]  # Remove empty lines
        return samples

# Read ATAC and RNA accession IDs
atac_SRRs = read_atac_accession()
rna_SRRs = read_rna_accession()


# Define all rule for generating libraries.csv
rule all:
    input:
        expand("{atac_srr}_{rna_srr}_libraries.csv", atac_srr=atac_SRRs, rna_srr=rna_SRRs)

# Rule to create libraries.csv
rule create_libraries_csv:
    output:
        "{atac_srr}_{rna_srr}_libraries.csv"
    run:
        atac_srr = wildcards.atac_srr
        rna_srr = wildcards.rna_srr
        with open(output[0], "w") as f:
            f.write("fastqs,sample,library_type\n")
            f.write(f"atac_seq/{atac_srr},{atac_srr},Chromatin Accessibility\n")
            f.write(f"rna_seq/{rna_srr},{rna_srr},Gene Expression\n")


Hello, I am trying to make a libraries.csv file for a pair of atac_seq and rna_seq accession numbers {SRRXXXXXX}. For now, I have 2 SRR for atac_seq, and 2 SRR for rna_seq; I want to generate a libraries.csv file for each pair, so I should end up with 2 {atac_srr}_{rna_srr}libraries.csv file.
With the code that I have, it generates it for all the possible combinations between the atac_seq and rna_seq accession numbers; I would like to generate it sequentially, meaning that the first SRR in the atac acession numbers list corresponds to the first element in the SRR in the rna accession numbers list; is there a possible way to do this?

I'm not sure I understand the details of what you need, but you can parse 2 lists in parallel by using for element1, element2 in zip(list1, list2):

you could do it as a for loop as sugested by Swifty. or if you want to keep the expand function:
expand("{atac_srr}_{rna_srr}_libraries.csv",zip, atac_srr=atac_SRRs, rna_srr=rna_SRRs)


Here's the link to the relevant part of the docs, which mentions this: https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#snakefiles-expand
